# MathML interpreter returns failure on valid expression

Tags: xml

I have the following expression

```
Interpreter["MathMLExpression"][<math>
<mfrac><mo>&DifferentialD;</mo><mrow><mo>&DifferentialD;</mo><mi>x</\
mi></mrow></mfrac><mo> ( </mo><mrow><mo> - 
</mo><mn>5</mn></mrow><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>3</mn></msup><mo> - 
</mo><mn>5</mn><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo> - 
</mo><mn>3</mn><mi>x</mi><mo> - </mo><mn>4</mn><mo> ) </mo>

</math>]
```

Which when I try to run, returns

```
Failure[ Message: Please enter a valid expression. Tag: Restriction failure]
```

But when I try it on Wolfram research's online interpreter, it returns fine. What am I doing wrong? 
(PS I have also tried ToExpression and HoldMathMLExpression--in Interpreter--and had no more luck)

Comment: Your expression should definitely be in a `String`... is that just a copy-paste error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToExpression` tries to get an `Expression` but what you've posted isn't valid Mathematica syntax. You want to use `ImportString` with `"MathML"` as the format. See [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MathML.html) for more.

```
mathExpr = "<math>
  <mfrac><mo>&DifferentialD;</mo><mrow><mo>&DifferentialD;</mo><mi>x</mi></\
mrow></mfrac>
  <mo> ( </mo>
  <mrow><mo> - 
  </mo><mn>5</mn></mrow><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>3</mn></msup>
  <mo> - 
  </mo><mn>5</mn><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>
  <mo> - </mo><mn>3</mn><mi>x</mi><mo> - </mo><mn>4</mn>
  <mo>)</mo>
  </math>";
ImportString[mathExpr, "MathML"] // RawBoxes
```

[image]

Comment: I was missing the raw boxes when I tried earlier. Thank you!